# Is any tool help me to query table by CONSTRAINTS rule?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a big database, the database have more than 1000 tables and have many 
table constraints rules. To remember all table constraints rule is too hard for me.Every day i need write many simple sql to query several tables. Writing so many sqls by hand is waste my time. Is there any tool to save my time to help me query table by CONSTRAINTS rule?

Answer (score 1):

if database is Oracle , you didn't try data dictionary ?

`USER_CONSTRAINTS` / `ALL_CONSTRAINTS` / `DBA_CONSTRAINTS` table ?

for query constrains on certain tables that own by current user

```
SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME, CONSTRAINT_TYPE, R_CONSTRAINT_NAME, STATUS
FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'CRUISES';
```

or you can try all constraints in table that user have right to query using `ALL_CONSTRAINTS` table

or  you can try on database level constraint using `DBA_CONSTRAINTS` table

both 3 tables share same column structure , so I won't repeat much .

Answer (score 1):

If you want a GUI tool, you could do worse than any of the following products:

- SQL Developer (Oracle)
- TOAD (Quest)
- PL/SQL Developer (Alround Automation)